# Ajax Cart is only loading all the time

Tags: ajax, cart

Since 2 days, the Ajax cart is only loading all the times, but not more happens:

https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/altra/altra-women-s-one-squared-running-shoes.html

After choosing the color and the click, add to cart, it start loading only.

What could this issue be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work on Chromium and Firefox on Linux, did you get this fixed or is it browser specific?

One thing to note is that your page is HTTPS, but you are making your request over http.  This will throw errors and some browsers may block the connection.  You should make your requests over HTTPS as well to fix this.

Comment: Hi Brady Cartmell, yes, we tried to fixed some issues about this.

And now I need to contact the developer from the theme, as some parts are from them. It not takes somehow https and instead it takes http only.